# MySQL: How to make an Index Scan run faster than a Full Table Scan?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I read from [MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/06/02/indexes-in-mysql/) that depending on the selectivity of a query, a full table scan can be faster than an index scan. Bearing such knowledge in mind, I experimented with a query having 12 `WHERE` criteria and one `HAVING` criterion on a table with 5 Million rows as per my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432255/mysql-enhancing-performance-without-cache). I observed that the full table scan is still much faster (**7.7sec**) than an index scan with a four-column index (**160sec**) that has 3% selectivity (161341/5000000).

My question is: "**Why is an index scan having 3% selectivity still 20 times slower than a full table scan? Is there a way to make the index scan faster?**"

Comment: For the above comparison, I did a `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` to flush system cache before the queries were run. Subsequent queries are always faster with index scan if I do not flush the cache. `Flush tables` command does not affect query speed here.

Comment: In a comment to your previous post say that the execution times above are measured on the first execution of the SQL. Is the performance difference the same if you ecxcute them more than one time?

Comment: @ Klas Lindbäck: If I do a flush (see my first comment) every time before each query, the index scan is always much slower than a full scan.

Comment: The problem seems to be related with how the table is loaded into teh cache. When you do a full table scan the table with be read using a sequential read. My guess is that when you use the index, the blocks will be read in the order they appear in the index, i.e. non-sequential. But that depends on your storage solution.

Answer (score 1):

> an index scan with a four-column index

The *order* of the columns in the index makes a difference to the performance. Put the most selective column first in the index. And it also depends on your query. A WHERE clause with `'x LIKE '%foo%'` will notuse the index effectively, but `'x LIKE 'foo%'` will be more effective.

Comment: It was mentioned in another [posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146930/mysql-sequence-of-multiple-column-indexes) that the order does not make a difference if the query uses all columns of the index.

Comment: You may like to check out my query [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432255/mysql-enhancing-performance-without-cache). The index used is (act, Type, tn, flA).

Comment: It is hard to judge which is the most selective column given that one query can be selective on column A and another query can be selective on column B, and so on.

Comment: @Ben: Then you can add multiple indexes and let the optimizer choose the best one for each query. Note that indexes are not free: It costs extra disk space and insert/update time will be slower.

Comment: Ok, I will test it out by reversing the column sequence in the index. But from application point of view, it is hard to judge which is the most selective column given that one query can be selective on column A and another query can be selective on column B, and so on.

Comment: @ Mark: My point is that the optimizer is not even able to pick out full table scan as having shorter query time, let alone choosing the right index.

Comment: @ Mark, reversing the column sequence in the index actually slows down the query speed by at least 50%. I am comparing a series of random queries.

Comment: @Ben: So in other words you've proven that the column order **does** in fact make a difference, which is exactly what said in my answer in the first place. OK so now you've now tried 2 of the 24 possible column orders. Only 22 left to try... (here's a hint: try the most selective column first.)

Comment: @ Mark: I agree with you on the direction of approach. Now my remaining question is, if I do a flush with `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`, the index query becomes much slower than a full scan. I have already set key_buffer_size to zero which ideally would have prevented a cache on the index. If my guess is correct, the index is cache somewhere else on my system, causing the speed to be blazing fast on subsequent query if I do not do a flush.